# How to share and embed geometric figures in a website

Tags: geometry, math-software

I was wondering if there was a website where I can create geometry figures and visuals, and embed this in a website, similar to how you can embed code with repl or github’s gist

Thank you!

Comment: I often use Geogebra.  Others use Desmos.

Comment: Will this work for modeling specific geometric figures? For instance, I tried creating the Rick’s paradox pattern in geogebra, but I found it tedious and tiring to do, since I could not measure the distance from one point to another. Is there a more appropriate  software that I can use (like TinkerCad)?

Comment: I’m also not exactly familiar with GeoGebra, and I have only used Desmos for graphing, so tips would be very helpful, thank you!